# Convention for describing quotient of rational number

Tags: rational-numbers, convention

Say I have an arbitrary rational $r = p/q$ and want to specify that this is in reduced form. Is the convention just to say that the fraction is in reduced form, or is there another way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be enough to state that the representation is in reduced form. If you want a more formal description, you could write that the condition $\gcd(p, q) = 1$ holds.